# I need the equivalent of this Count with Case for Firebird 3 database

Tags: sqlite, count, case, firebird

I need the equivalent of this Count with Case for a Firebird 3 database. I get an error when I try it:

```
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid usage of boolean expression.
```

I was just recently introduced to the Case command and I can't seem to rework it myself. I managed to get it to work with SQLite just fine.

The intent is to do an AND operation, the Where can't do an AND because the keywords are in rows.

```
SELECT Count((CASE WHEN keywords.keyword LIKE '%purchased%'
              THEN 1 END) AND
             (CASE WHEN keywords.keyword LIKE '%item%'
              THEN 1 END)) AS TRows
FROM products
     LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords_products ON
       products.product_rec_id = keywords_products.product_rec_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords ON
       keywords_products.keyword_rec_id = keywords.keyword_rec_id
WHERE (keywords.keyword LIKE '%purchased%' OR
       keywords.keyword LIKE '%item%')
```

I have three SQLite tables, a products table, a keywords_products table, and a keywords table.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_rec_id  INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    name            VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE keywords_products (
    keyword_rec_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product_rec_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE keywords (
    keyword_rec_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
    keyword        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE
);
```

The *keywords_products* table holds the the record id of a product and a record id of a keyword. Each product can be assigned multiple keywords in the *keywords* table.

The *keyword* table looks like this:

```
keyword_rec_id  keyword
--------------  -----------
60              melee
43              scifi
87              water
```

The *keywords_products* table looks like this (one keyword can be assigned to many products):

```
keyword_rec_id  product_rec_id
--------------  --------------
43              1
60              1
43              2
87              3
```

The products table looks like this:

```
product_rec_id  name
--------------  --------------
1               Scifi Melee Weapons
2               Scifi Ray Weapon
3               Lake House
```

Comment: What is the intended meaning of that `CASE`-expression, because it doesn't make much sense to me. Maybe you should replace the `AND` by a `+`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel using plus would make no sense also w.r.t. COUNT aggregate for `NULL+1 = NULL`. I guess with have a case of XYZ here.

Comment: @Arioch'The It depends. If the intention is to count where both conditions are true, then it would behave the same, assuming SQLite coerces 1 to true when using `AND`, and has correct null behavior (or if count would not count `false`). Given the lack of an explanation of the intended behavior that is just guessing though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel as far as all he needs is mere counting he has to drop CASE altogether and use proper WHERE instead. That is why I suspect XYZ case. The TS seems to see nails everywhere, because he got used to handle a hammer. When in this particular case I guess he does not need it. Also with such a WHERE his joins LEFTiness is redundant too I guess.

Comment: The intent is to do an AND operation, the Where can't do an AND because the keywords are in rows.

Comment: By definition, AND operation is a method, not an intent. If you intent is "do an AND operation" then just issue `select 1 from rdb$database where (1=1) and (2=2)` and here it is, you just did an AND operation. If that would be a real intent. But it is not. You have some other intent. You just stuck in "must trigger AND operation" mode, mistaking tool and goal.  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem

Comment: If you can not understand and explain what you want, you can neither make good solution nor get good suggestion other than by mere chance. You are not the first person who mistake goal and method. The link shows how typical it is. You may consider yourself above the typical faults. It would nor harm anyone but yourself.

Comment: Please show what the result should be and explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to count how many rows there are where both conditions are true.

The error occurs because you can't use `AND` between integer values. The values must be true booleans.

So, change your code to

```
Count((CASE WHEN keywords.keyword LIKE '%purchased%'
          THEN TRUE END) AND
         (CASE WHEN keywords.keyword LIKE '%item%'
          THEN TRUE END))
```

However that is far too complex. You can simplify your expression to

```
count(nullif(
    keywords.keyword LIKE '%purchased%' and keywords.keyword LIKE '%item%',
    false))
```

The use of [`NULLIF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-nullif) is needed because `COUNT` will count all non-NULL values (as required by the SQL standard), and `false` is non-NULL as well. So to achieve the (assumed) desired effect, we transform `false` to `NULL` using `NULLIF`.

Comment: ....so complex hacks when all is needed was `COUNT(1)` and proper (one term changed) `WHERE` clause. Poor Firebird...

Comment: @Arioch'The That depends on whether or not the code from the question was **simplified** (leaving out other details).

Comment: @Arioch'The I will try with count(1) and see what I get. I believe I tried that and I was not getting the results I expected because I have other tables joined in other queries. I had also tried boolean here before Mark's answer but I had THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END and that was what confused me as Firebird did not accept that. I have to simplify my queries because they are getting out of hand and I am very poor at SQL.

Comment: You would also have to formulate your task and then formulate WHERE clause to exactly represent your task. For example do you mean OR, AND or XOR ? For example should AND case be counted as 1 or as 2? Etc, etc, etc. "Proper formulation of task is half of the solution". That is twice true with SQL, which is offshoot of mathematical set theory, thus pen-and-paper is often more efficient for designing and debugging queries than any handbook.

Comment: This solution is not working for other tables with a similar structure. The only difference is the names of the fields. What could possibly be the cause? If it's working for one it should work with the other. I am able to retrieve the data OK just like with the Keywords' tables but not Count, it returns a value of 0.

Comment: @nDelphi I suggest you post a new question, provide relevant DDL of tables, sample data, your attempted query and the expected and actual result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ONE single CASE expression with multiple WHEN branches.

Making Boolean functions of distinct CASE expressions just makes no sense - the CASE is not Boolean function itself.

You can see rules and an example at [`CASE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-commons.html#fblangref40-commons-conditional-case).

```
case
  when Age >= 18 then 'Yes'
  when Age <  18 then 'No'
end;
```

Remake you two CASE clauses to a single CASE clause following this pattern.

---

However, you only use CASE when you can not move filters and conditions into standard part of SQL select. Normal approach would be to minimize data that SQL engine has to fetch, using pre-filtering. The CASE uses post-filtering, it makes SQL engine to fetch all the data, regardless if it needs it or not, and then discard the unneeded fetched data. That is redundant work slowing down the process.

In your case you already extracted the condition into WHERE clause, that is good.

```
SELECT
...

WHERE (keywords.keyword LIKE '%purchased%') 
   OR (keywords.keyword LIKE '%item%')
```

Since you pre-filter your data stream to always contain "item" or "purchase" then the CASE clause of yours would always return 1 on all rows selected under this WHERE pre-filtering. Hence - just remove the redundant CASE clause and put "1" instead.

```
SELECT Count(1)
FROM products
  LEFT JOIN keywords_products ON products.product_rec_id = keywords_products.product_rec_id
  LEFT JOIN keywords ON keywords_products.keyword_rec_id = keywords.keyword_rec_id
WHERE (keywords.keyword LIKE '%purchased%') 
   OR (keywords.keyword LIKE '%item%')
```

---

Now, given that WHERE clause is processed logically after JOINing, this your query de facto transformed LEFT JOINs into FULL JOINs ( your WHERE clause just discards rows with NULL "keyword" column values  ) but aghain in unreliable and inefficient method. Since you do not want to have "keyword is NULL" kind of rows anyway - just convert your left joins to normal joins.

Comment: Thank you. I will study the JOINs later today when I get the chance. The intent is to do an AND operation after the Where as the keywords are in rows.

Comment: @nDelphi you may put AND into WHERE. As of now no one can understand exactly what you want. You may start with explaining the problem in human terms, then perhaps you would rethink and better understand it.